# Display problem on browsers

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, display, 18.04, ubuntu-mate

I'm facing some font and display problems on browsers...

[image]

Notice that the "ITSFOSS.COM" is displayed somewhat weirdly, somewhat cut-off, also happens on Facebook notifications menu and many other places...

The problem occurs on both Firefox and Chrome.

Anyway to fix this issue?

I'm using Ubuntu MATE 18.04...